# Magento 2: How to use an image within a link

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, image, link

Attaching a link to an image is not an uncommon action to take, and I'm trying to accomplish this within the `default.xml` of my theme. We have a static image of a google maps location, and we want it to link to Google's map app.

**XML**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="location.link">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<img src="/pub/media/logo/default/location-map.png" />]]></argument>
    <argument name="href" xsi:type="string">https://goo.gl/maps/XSKNf</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

The xml above correctly renders a clickable link that goes to the proper location, but the `img` tag itself is rendered as text, not as html. Removing `CDATA` results in the argument not being parsed.

It's obvious I'm coming at this wrong, and given M2's relative newness, I've not been able to find an example that shows a way.

Is what I am asking possible?

**NOTE** **
I am aware that I could just create a template file to accomplish this, but I'm asking if there is another method that would work. I would like to avoid creating unnecessary templates, if possible, just to render a single line of static html.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the code  of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link` carefully you will notice the label is escaped :

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
   if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
      return parent::_toHtml();
   }

   return 'getLinkAttributes() . ' >' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getLabel()) . '';
}
```

But you can also notice that you can set a template that should solve the problem. The phtml should be something like :

`<li><a <?php $block->getLinkAttributes(); ?>> <?php echo $block->getLabel(); ?></a></li>`

The label is not escaped here.

Comment: Right, I know I can set a template.  I'm updating my question to clarify. I'm asking if there is a way to accomplish this without creating a template file for what amounts to a single line of html.

Comment: As the escapeHtml call is not conditional, I would say no